# Entity Framework 4 - TPH Inheritance in Features CTP5 (code first) with "IS NULL" discriminator

Tags: c#-4.0, poco, code-first, entity-framework-ctp5, table-per-hierarchy

Hey guys,
I'm trying to create a TPH mapping on a hierarchy where the discriminating clause is the classical "IS NOT NULL" / "IS NULL" case.

Here is the example, database wise:

```
CREATE TABLE info.EducationTypes
(
   ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
   Name NVARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
   FKParentID INT NULL REFERENCES info.EducationTypes(ID)
)
```

the idea is to have a class hierarchy like the following one:

```
public abstract class EducationType
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class MainEducationType : EducationType
{
    public IEnumerable<SubEducationType> SubTypes { get; set; }
}

public class SubEducationType : EducationType
{
    public MainEducationType MainType { get; set; }
}
```

I got this schema "working" in the classic xml model, but I really can't find a way to get it working by using the code first approach. This is what I tried...

```
var educationType = modelBuilder.Entity<EducationType>();
educationType.Map<MainEducationType>(m => m.Requires("FKParentID").HasValue(null));
educationType.Map<SubEducationType>(m => m.Requires("FKParentID"));
```

Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, having a null value for the discriminator column in TPH mapping is not currently supported in CTP5. This is confirmed by EF team on [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/adonetefx/thread/a8a374b5-61b5-4bad-826d-8c1ec86b989e) and also [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-CA/adonetefx/thread/dc836fe0-081a-4bc0-b3fe-2550cbee1c20). They are looking at it to see if they can make it work for the RTM though.