# Code First: TPT inheritance - Specify a different name for the primary key column in each table

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, ef-code-first

I've posted my problem on codeplex http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/2087.
There are also some questions posted here but they are not successfully answered.

See

[Mapping TPT in EF Code First 4.1 w/ Different Primary Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681169/mapping-tpt-in-ef-code-first-4-1-w-different-primary-keys)

[Entity Framework 4 - TPT Inheritance in Features CTP5 (code first): rename foreign key column on inherited table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019972/entity-framework-4-tpt-inheritance-in-features-ctp5-code-first-rename-forei)

[How can I use TPT inheritance models when primary keys have different names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5490134/how-can-i-use-tpt-inheritance-models-when-primary-keys-have-different-names)

**Is it now possible to have different column names for the primary keys when using TPT?
May be with 6.1.0**

Answer (score 0):

In TPT you're essentially do not want to declare the key in the subclasses, you'd miss the point otherwise.
If you must have a different Id name, just make proxy properties in the subclasses mapping to the base Id one.

```
public class BaseEntity
{
  public int Id { get; set; }    
}

public abstract class SubEntity : BaseEntity
{
  public BaseId
  {
    get => Id;
    set => Id = value;
  }
}
```

Consider marking the sub fields as [`NotMapped`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute), which in case you shouldn't include them in your LINQ queries.

Answer (score 0):

With EF 6.4 I was able to use the ColumnAttribute to rename the Primary Key column in the dependent class

```
[Table("Person")]
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public virtual int PersonId { get; set; }

    // Person atributes...
}

[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee : Person
{
    [Column("EmployeeId")] // <- Name of the primary Key column in the Database
    public override int PersonId { get; set }

    // Employee Attributes

}
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at this code snip. Its work correct for me:

```
public partial class Person
{
    // Any other PK name can thrown an exception
    public int ID { get; set; }
}

public partial class Employee : Person
{
    // Hide base class ID
    private new int ID { get; set }

    // Define derived class ID (that wrapped inherited ID)
    [NotMapped]
    public int EmployeeID
    {
        get { return base.PersonID; }
        set { base.PersonID = value; }
    }
}
```

Now, we must rename the inherited ID (with fluent API) for database table:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>()
        .Property(e => e.ID)
        .HasColumnName("EmployeeID");
}
```