# Code First - Mapping when the Discriminator IS NULL or NOT NULL

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, code-first, table-per-hierarchy, table-per-subclass

I want to use TPH Inheritance in EF5 Code First. I want to base it on whether a column in the database is null or not.

I found this link indicating it was not possible in EF4. [Entity Framework 4 - TPH Inheritance in Features CTP5 (code first) with "IS NULL" discriminator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5019717/entity-framework-4-tph-inheritance-in-features-ctp5-code-first-with-is-null)

Has this been fixed in EF5? If so, what is the syntax?

Answer (score 0):

see the discussion and answer at:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/1045bd0c-29dd-4e23-9d50-2f315e89eefd

It hasn't been implemented in EF5